# How to make a user on my website ping a specific ip address?

Tags: html, web, ip, ping

I'm wondering how website like this one : https://ping.eu/ping/ manage to make our ip ping an other ip and get the result.

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Doesn't. A PHP script(on the server) will most likely do it with "PHP Sockets". Have a look at
this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Else it could use exec() function, but that would be a security flaw.

So to answer your question: The website will ping the IP address not the 'client'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nevertheless, is there software to specify a source ping address?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you mean by 'specify a source ping address'. Do you want an address to test a ping? If so, try '8.8.8.8', google's servers. They won't mind.

Comment: No, for example, my IP is A, the server I want to ping has IP B but I want to ping it with an other IP (C) which is not mine. Or, at least, make an estimation of how much time B will take to respond to C.

Comment: OK, I am with you. Yes, a Javascript Function could handle that and tat would indeed be client side pinging. See, @Max Voisard answer below. I haven't looked through it but, it could be a working JS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ping a server, i.e. an actual web address/URL like www.google.com, you can look at this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/ or GitHub repository https://github.com/jdfreder/pingjs.

Here's some code from the JSFiddle:

```
function Pinger_ping(ip, callback) {
  if(!this.inUse) {
     this.inUse = true;
     this.callback = callback
     this.ip = ip;

     var _that = this;
     this.img = new Image();
     this.img.onload = function() {_that.good();};
     this.img.onerror = function() {_that.good();};

     this.start = new Date().getTime();
     this.img.src = "http://" + ip;
     this.timer = setTimeout(function() { _that.bad();}, 1500);
  }
}
```

Another way to ping a server/web address is to use JavaScript and the `XMLHttpRequest()` function it supports:

HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function http_ping(fqdn) {
var NB_ITERATIONS = 4; // number of loop iterations
var MAX_ITERATIONS = 5; // beware: the number of simultaneous XMLHttpRequest is limited by the browser!
var TIME_PERIOD = 1000; // 1000 ms between each ping
var i = 0;
var over_flag = 0;
var time_cumul = 0;
var REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 9000;
var TIMEOUT_ERROR = 0;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "HTTP ping for " + fqdn + "</br>";

var ping_loop = setInterval(function() {


    // let's change non-existent URL each time to avoid possible side effect with web proxy-cache software on the line
        url = "http://" + fqdn + "/a30Fkezt_77" + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);

        if (i < MAX_ITERATIONS) {

            var ping = new XMLHttpRequest();

            i++;
            ping.seq = i;
            over_flag++;

            ping.date1 = Date.now();

            ping.timeout = REQUEST_TIMEOUT; // it could happen that the request takes a very long time

            ping.onreadystatechange = function() { // the request has returned something, let's log it (starting after the first one)

                if (ping.readyState == 4 && TIMEOUT_ERROR == 0) {
                    over_flag--;
                    if (ping.seq > 1) {
                        delta_time = Date.now() - ping.date1;
                        time_cumul += delta_time;
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "</br>http_seq=" + (ping.seq-1) + " time=" + delta_time + " ms</br>";
                    }
                }
            }

            ping.ontimeout = function() {
                TIMEOUT_ERROR = 1;
            }
            ping.open("GET", url, true);
            ping.send();
        }

        if ((i > NB_ITERATIONS) && (over_flag < 1)) { // all requests are passed and have returned

            clearInterval(ping_loop);
            var avg_time = Math.round(time_cumul / (i - 1));
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "</br> Average ping latency on " + (i-1) + " iterations: " + avg_time + "ms </br>";

        }
        if (TIMEOUT_ERROR == 1) { // timeout: data cannot be accurate
            clearInterval(ping_loop);
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<br/> THERE WAS A TIMEOUT ERROR <br/>";
            return;
        }
    }, TIME_PERIOD);
}
```

But, of course, these are web addresses, not IP addresses, so I'm not sure if that's what you're aiming for. I'm also not sure if you're looking for the amount of time spent to get the connection and the number of packets and bytes sent and received, or if you just want to validate the connection. The above code does all of those things. For IP addresses, you can try an AJAX request to ping a server, which only sees if there is a connection using YOUR SERVER'S IP address, NOT THE USER'S CLIENT, like this:

```
client --AJAX-- yourserver --ICMP ping-- targetservers
```

You could also try:

- Using a Java applet with `isReachable`
- Writing a server-side script which pings, and using AJAX to communicate to your server-side script
- You might also be able to ping in Flash (using `ActionScript`)

One last hypothetical and unorthodox way to get an IP address is to inspect and view the source of the website you mentioned and copy some code, mostly JavaScript, and test it on your end and try to implement it.